Trying to build a recipe/ingredient tracker in Google Sheets with conditional formatting
I'm playing a game with a crafting system in it, but no convenient way to see recipes and inventory, so I built my own. I have an Inventory column listing ingredients and quantities, and then necessary ingredients listed under each recipe title.
I want to highlight the ingredients under each recipe when I have them available based on their values in the inventory list.
I looked into things like index/match and vlookup but I'm lost. My thinking is I need to accomplish three steps (where A=list of ingredients, B=their quantities, D2:G11=recipes):

Test for B>0. { =if(B2>0, [formula that somehow applies step 2], )?? }
If true, find corresponding column A values within the range D2:G11. {?????}
Apply formatting. {put resulting formula from above into conditional formatting rule?}

Orrr am I doing this backwards and I should start with some kind of array formula over the recipes range which then looks for the corresponding inventory entry and then tests it? So like... For a given cell (let's say D6) within the arrayformula range:

Which cell in column A matches the value in D6? (Let's say it's A10.)
Is the value immediately to the right of A10 (B10) >0?
If step 2 = TRUE, then apply formatting to original cell D6.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to set this up?
Example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S7ph_0hd5ZbE42jI1wwl2tp5P-ydh_4hlFrvV0XRzBI/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022
I've never really done any coding, so this kind of thinking is very new to me. Thank you for your help!

Here's one formula you can try out, using it as the custom function for conditional formatting:
=ROWS(FILTER($A$2:$B, $A$2:$A=D1, $B$2:$B>0))>0


In the formula, D1 should be the first cell in your conditional-formatted range.
FILTER selects the rows of the ingredients list with that name and quantity >0; ROWS computes the number of such rows.
References

FILTER
ROWS


Oooh! That is SO much simpler than what I was thinking; it never would have even occurred to me that I could use a number of rows that way. Thank you so much!!

You can simply use COUNTIFS.
Apply the following formula to the range D2:G (or D2:G11 if you don't want an open range)
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,D2,$B:$B,">0")

